# No se ha podido encontrar la dirección ip del servidor en moviles

Tags: android, asp.net, google-chrome, dns, ip

Tengo un Api alojada en IIS 10 en una red Local , en cualquier PC puedo acceder de manera remota solo con el nombre de la PC que utilizo como servidor , pero en moviles (tablet, celulares..) no lo resuelve a la ip del servidor

**Por ejemplo:** Desde el navegador web:

```
https://NOMBRE-SERVIDOR ---> se deberia resolver en la ip del servidor--> https://192.168.1.2
```

En cualquier PC de la misma red puedo acceder correctamente, pero **NO** en **MOVILES** (tablet, celulares..) que también están conectados a la misma red.

Tengo el inconveniente que el ISP es dinamico , es decir siempre cambia de ip , asi que utilizo el nombre del servidor

Este es el error en los moviles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pregunta**

Como lograria que tambien los moviles accedan con el nombre del servidor, que configuracion extra debo hacer?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Tienes algún DNS local?

Comment: @fredyfx en el servidor esta con la configuración por defecto , detectar automáticamente, no entiendo que esta pasando realmente

Answer (score 0):

Pero si estas en la misma red, podrias poner el servidor con una ip estatica, ya que esa ip solo funciona en tu red local no para el exterior, y asi podrias acceder desde cualquier dispositivo en tu red.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario , poner una ip estática en el servidor era lo que hacia antes, pero me traía  varios inconvenientes , aveces esa ip la ganaba otro dispositivo y ocurrian conflictos , cuando el moden  lo reiniciaban se borra la ip statica , asi que ahora coloco el nombre del servidor , excelente hasta aqui pero en moviles no se resuelve a la ip del servidor

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es en la configuración de tu modem limitar la asignacion de ips automaticas y dejar excluida la ip fija por ejemplo. tu ip del servidor es la 192.168.1.250 entonces limitas tu dhcp en el rango de 192.168.1.2 hasta el 192.168.1.249 obviamente si reseteas tu modem esta configuración se perderia.

Comment: Es justo lo que quiero intentar , pero por ejemplo un día dejo la IP estática y a la otra semana regreso a ver el servidor y esa configuración desapareció , asi que esa configuracion no es seguro , ya que otro usuario lo puede remover , por esa razon busco resolver este inconveniente del  acceso a moviles